# read txt file with php and put result in array

Tags: php

Hi guys i need a guid on read txt file i have a file named `mw2.log` and this file have mutiple line and per line i have `ip:port` like as:

```
1.1.1.1:222
2.2.2.2:3333
3.3.3.3:888
....
```

with this method i can read file but i want to put every line in array and seprat ip and port and return with `$ip`  and `$port` result because i want to send ip's and port's throw POST method to other file named `add.php`

my code is:

```
<?php

$file = "mw2.log";
$source_file = fopen( $file, "r" ) or die("Couldn't open $file");
if (!feof($source_file)) {
$buffer = fread($source_file, 4096);  // use a buffer of 4KB

//some stuff here

fclose($source_file);
} else {
// error opening the file.
}


//$form_type = 'callofduty4';
//$form_ip = '37.187.71.163';
//$form_c_port = '16044';


$Curl_Session = curl_init('http://127.0.0.1/serverlist/lgsl_files/robot.php');
curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "form_type=$form_type&form_ip=$form_ip&form_c_port=$form_c_port");
curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_exec ($Curl_Session);
curl_close ($Curl_Session);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `file()` and `explode()` for this...

```
<?php
    $ip_arr=file('mw2.log');
    $ips= array();
    $ports=array();
    foreach($ip_arr as $val)
    {
        $val=explode(':',$val);
        array_push($ips,$val[0]);
        array_push($ports,$val[1]);
    }
 print_r($ips);
 print_r($ports);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1.1.1.1
    [1] => 2.2.2.2
    [2] => 3.3.3.3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 222

    [1] => 3333

    [2] => 888
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're confident this will be a relatively small and well-formed file, it's probably easier to use file() like so:

```
$connectionParams = file("mw2.log");
/*
$connectionParams will look like array('1.1.1.1:222', '2.2.2.2:3333', '3.3.3.3:888') at this point
*/
if ($connectionParams !== false) {
    foreach ($connectionParams as $connectionInfo) {
        // some stuff
    }
} else {
    // error opening the file
}
```

Is this the question you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

```
while (!feof($source_file)) {
    $buffer = fgets($source_file); // read a line    

    $parts = explode(':', $buffer); // seperate ip and ports part
    $ip[] = $parts[0];
    $ports[] = $parts[1];

}
fclose($source_file);

print_r($ip);
print_r($ports);
```

$ip has the ip address now and $ports has the ports.

Answer (score 0):

My take

```
$lines = file('file.txt');
$output = array();
$count = 0;
foreach($lines as $v) {
    $parts = explode(":", $v);
    $output[$count]['ip'] = $parts[0];
    $output[$count]['port'] = $parts[1];
    $count++; 
}

print_r($output);
```

Comment: Thank you all of rply work but i have result like this: ` Array ( [0] => Array ( [ip] => 201.251.233.71 [port] => 28965 ) [1] => Array ( [ip] => 37.187.71.163 [port] => 16044 ) `  but how i can put this result in my CURL with post method my means i can just post one ip and port but i need to post all of them?